# c++ boost program options allow long short option

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I am trying to allow "long-short" options using boost (version 1.46). I was under the impression that enabling the *disguise* boost style would allow such a thing. Given this code:

```
  // Declare the supported options.
  boost::program_options::options_description desc( "Allowed options" );
  desc.add_options()
    ( "help,h", "produce help message" )
    ( "RunTimeE,rtttt", boost::program_options::value<std::string>(), "RunTimeE Version" )
    ;

  boost::program_options::variables_map vm;
  boost::program_options::store( boost::program_options::command_line_parser( argc, argv )
                                 .options( desc )
                                 .style( boost::program_options::command_line_style::unix_style
                                         | boost::program_options::command_line_style::allow_long_disguise )
                                 .run(),
                                 vm );

  boost::program_options::notify( vm );    

  if (vm.count("help")) {
    cout << desc << "\n";
    return 1;
  }
  if (vm.count("RunTimeE")) {
    cout << vm["RunTimeE"].as<std::string>() << endl;
    return 1;
  }
```

Will produce:

```
./output  --help
Allowed options:
  -h [ --help ]         produce help message
  -r [ --RunTimeE ] arg RunTimeE Version
```

But I want it to produce:

```
./output  --help
Allowed options:
  -h [ --help ]             produce help message
  -rtttt [ --RunTimeE ] arg RunTimeE Version
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible without writing your own [custom parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html). You are specifying a long option `RunTimeE` and a short option `rtttt` but short options are by definition only one character. You can use long options with a single dash by specifying  `allow_long_disguise` but I don't see that allowing you to have two long options. In fact what would be the point of having two long options over a long and short?

Answer (score 1):

Is it an option to create two long options?

If you don't think it's nice to have two values associated with the same setting int he variable map, refer it to the same setting:

<kbd>**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d931456a5ecad49)**</kbd>

Output:

```
echo ------; ./a.out -h
echo ------; ./a.out -rtttt asdasdads
echo ------; ./a.out -RunTimeE qwe7
echo ------; ./a.out --rtttt 99
------
Allowed options:
  -h [ --help ]         produce help message
  --RunTimeE arg        RunTimeE Version
  --rtttt arg           RunTimeE Version

------
vm[rtttt]:    asdasdads
optRunTimeE: asdasdads
------
vm[RunTimeE]: qwe7
optRunTimeE: qwe7
------
vm[rtttt]:    99
optRunTimeE: 99
```

Listing:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Declare the supported options.
    boost::program_options::options_description desc("Allowed options");

    std::string optRunTimeE;
    desc.add_options()
        ("help,h", "produce help message")
        ("RunTimeE", boost::program_options::value<std::string>(&optRunTimeE), "RunTimeE Version")
        ("rtttt",    boost::program_options::value<std::string>(&optRunTimeE), "RunTimeE Version")
        ;

    boost::program_options::variables_map vm;
    boost::program_options::store(
            boost::program_options::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
            .options(desc)
            .style(
                boost::program_options::command_line_style::unix_style |
                boost::program_options::command_line_style::allow_long_disguise)
            .run(),
            vm);

    boost::program_options::notify(vm);

    if (vm.count("help")) {
        std::cout << desc << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (vm.count("RunTimeE")) std::cout << "vm[RunTimeE]: " << vm["RunTimeE"].as<std::string>() << std::endl;
    if (vm.count("rtttt"))    std::cout << "vm[rtttt]:    " << vm["rtttt"].as<std::string>()    << std::endl;

    std::cout << "optRunTimeE: " << optRunTimeE << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This won't work with the bool switches: `po::bool_switch()->default_value(false)`. You have to process them separately per each flag and decide what to do with flags duplications/intersections. This obligates an overhead code additionally to the boost code.

Comment: @Andry good observation. Here's a workaround that's not too inelegant, by replacing the default notifier: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed32d31cb8f32572